# how to hide chrome created website app title-bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-app

I created an application extension from chrome, and I want to hide the bar of information:
[image]

I want to hie the green area, which is show's in the above picture.

Comment: A `google-chrome-app` is a very specific technology stack, not just any app. It doesn't look like you're using it, otherwise your app's window would look differently as you would create it with chrome.app.window.create.

Comment: and how i hide this green area ?

Comment: My comment meant your question seems to have the wrong technology tag. Which means it's impossible to say what happens there.

Answer (score 6):

Create a shortcut on your Desktop and add the following start parameters:

```
"PATH to chrome.exe" -app="http://192.168.1.1"
```

The window should look like this:

[image: Chrome App Window]

You can also set a custom shortcut icon if you want.

Comment: Brilliant stuff!

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273909 Try this, but otherwise I really don't know. Not a MAC user. The arguments should be the same across different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `chrome://flags`

Search for `secure` and find "Insecure origins treated as secure", #unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure (can be stated differently).

it provides a field where you can write addresses that you want to exclude, i.e. assume they are secure.
[image]